# How to navigate in a CupertinoApp

Tags: redux, dart, flutter, flutter-redux

With a `MaterialApp` you can provide the `navigatorKey` and use that in your middleware to redirect the user if necessary (as it's done in the flutter redux example).

But `CupertinoApp` doesn’t have a `navigatorKey`.

What we are doing now is to add the `context` to the action so we have access to it in the middleware, and can then user `Navigator.of(context)`, but this seems very wrong.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Make a Pull Request

Comment: @RémiRousselet to the `CupertinoApp` to add `navigatorKey` you mean?

Comment: Yes exactly. If should be really easy to do

Comment: Mh Ok. I just didn't know whether this is the proper way to do it, or if there are other trivial solutions to this problem that don't require a PR. But if that will make it easier I'll tackle it.

Comment: Well you should be able to do without it by using `builder` property though

Comment: @RémiRousselet would you mind elaborating a bit?

Comment: By using `builder` you could create your middleware here, so that it is binded to the Navigator

Comment: Mh ok, but when using the `CupertinoApp` routes, we don't write our code in the `builder`, and the `context` from the parent widget's `builder` can't be used because the `Navigator` is not available there...

Comment: Navigator is available inside `CupertinoApp`'s builder

Comment: How? The `builder` function provides `context` and `widget`. How do I get the navigator our of that? `Navigator.of(context)` doesn't work in that context, because this context is not a child of a navigator (or similar).

Comment: `Navigator.of(context)` does work in that context. It is a child of navigator. It's made exactly for that

Comment: We have a `CupertinoApp` (with `routes`), and when trying to access the `Navigator` inside the `builder` like this: `Navigator.of(context)` we get: `Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator`

Comment: Indeed sorry. But that's a bug then. As it's possible with MaterialApp. Consider making an issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`navigatorKey` has been added to the `CupertinoApp`.